# The feature 'nullable reference types' is currently in preview and *unsupported*

Tags: c#, nullable, visual-studio-2019, c#-8.0, nullable-reference-types

I want to add into my C# 8.0 projects Nullable@1.1.1 package but I don't want to enable it yet. Just add.

I'm using Visual Studio 2019 v16.3.10 and I installed it on each project by ***Manage NuGet Packages for Solution...*** option.

During rebuild of my solution I'm getting the error:

> The feature 'nullable reference types' is currently in Preview and
>   *unsupported*. To use Preview features, use the 'preview' language version.

This error is exists for only 6 from 49 projects in my solution.

I removed from all of projects the LangVersion tag in favor one LangVersion tag into Directory.Build.props, so my Directory.Build.props looks like:

```
<Project>
    <PropertyGroup>
        <LangVersion>latest</LangVersion>
        <AutoGenerateBindingRedirects>true</AutoGenerateBindingRedirects>
        <GenerateBindingRedirectsOutputType>true</GenerateBindingRedirectsOutputType>
    </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

I decided to don't add a Nullable tag with disable value to this file because it is the default value of Nullable package so it was not make a sense.

How can I solve that?

I have to ask because all of tips about Nullable are about ***how to enable it*** and didn't reply me for my error.

---

Edit:

I had to add Nullable@1.1.1 by NuGet Package because my projects are on .NET Framework 4.8.:

> ***Nullability Attributes in Older Projects***
>
> In order to actually use
>   these attributes, they need to be defined. If you are using .NET
>   Standard 2.1 or .NET Core 3.0, that’s already done for you. Otherwise
>   you’ll have to create them as part of your project.
>
> The traditional way of handling this would be to create a new .NET
>   Core 3 project, the use F12 to reverse engineer the desired
>   attributes. Then you can paste it into your project and add any
>   missing details, which for attributes only takes a few minutes.
>
> An easier way is to simply install the Nullable package by Manuel
>   Römer. This will copy the NullableAttributes.cs file into your
>   project, which includes all of the necessary attributes. This package
>   has no compiled component, it is just the one source code file.
>
> Either way, ensure all of the attributes are marked as "internal", not
>   public. This is to avoid collisions with other libraries that may also
>   be back-porting the attributes.

[Using C# 8 and Nullable Reference Types in .NET Framework](https://www.infoq.com/articles/CSharp-8-Framework/)

Comment: Is there a reason you're using the nuget package instead of the built in feature? To use the native feature I think you just need to upgrade VS to a newer version

Comment: "To use Preview features, use the 'preview' language version" What about this?

Comment: We're using nullable with our .Net Framework 4.8 projects on VS2019 v16.3.10 without having to use any NuGet packages. All we had to do was add the `<LangVersion>latest</LangVersion>` to our .csproj files (which are all in "legacy format"). However, we had to add `#nullable enable` to *every* source file because it seems that you can't turn it on globally for a legacy format .csproj project.

Comment: @JoePhillips my projects are on .NET Framework 4.8 so I have to do like that - by NuGet package. See my edited part of ask.

Comment: @MatthewWatson erevything is well when you've go a NET Standard 2.1 or .NET Core 3.0 projects. I've got the projects on .NET Framework 4.8, so as you can see on my edited part of ask - I had to use it by NuGet package.

Comment: @Presto Matthew Watson answered about .NET Framework 4.8, not .NET Core or Standard 2.1. What you used is a third-party package. There's no guarantee it will work. Have you tried Matthew's suggestion? If your project uses the new csproj format, have you tried adding the `Nullable` element directly?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I'm not sure but it seems to be the problem with web projects. On other projects Nullable is working well. Only web projects have this issue.

Comment: @Presto Razor views use an older C# version, that's not controlled by the *project* settings. That's a problem with ASP.NET Core 2.2 as well.